# How do you convert all timestamps to Unix timestamps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My iOS developer was asking me to provide all timestamps in a JSON structure to be Unix timestamps, as the number of seconds that have elapsed since "00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970", not counting leap seconds.

Seeing that all of my data was stored in strings on the server, I would like to create a method to convert all of the timestamps to Unix timestamps as an integer.

In other words, I need to convert:

```
{
  "created_at" => "2015-01-18T00:58:58.903Z", 
  "updated_at" => "2015-01-18T00:58:58.903Z", 
  "user_id" => 1, 
  "status_id" => 1
}
```

to:

```
{
  "created_at" => 1421542604, 
  "updated_at" => 1421542604, 
  "user_id" => 1, 
  "status_id" => 1
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you ask for help with code, you need to show us what you've tried. With your code we can directly address what wasn't working. Without it it looks like you're asking us to write the code for you at worst, and at best we can only write code that is unrelated to yours, which you'd then have to shoehorn into place.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the following rspec, then realized I need to modify the default `as_json` method to perform this conversion:

```
expect(response_json).to eq(
  {
    'created_at'    => user.created_at.as_json,
    'updated_at'    => user.updated_at.as_json,
    'user_id'       => user.user_id,
    'status_id'     => user.status_id
  }
)
```

I then created `/config/initializers/unix_timestamps.rb` and it worked:

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def as_json
    self.to_time.to_i
  end
end
```

Comment: As a side note, avoid overriding `as_jsons`. What would happen if in the future, another developer will ask you to return Roman numbers? You will have only one method, and multiple representations. Write a serializer object that takes your object as input, and use the serializer to convert the need.